# Duplicates in HashSet after deserialzation C#

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, hashset

I have a `HashSet` as seen below:

```
public name {get; set; }

[JsonProperty(ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace, TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
public ICollection<T> data { get; set; }

public MyClass(string name)
{
    name = name;
    data = new HashSet<T>(new CustomComparer());
}
```

The comparer looks like:

```
public class CustomComparer: EqualityComparer<T>
{
    public override bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x.val, y.val, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return $"{obj?.val?.ToLowerInvariant()}-{obj?.val?.ToLowerInvariant()}".GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now, I have a unit test where I first create an instance of MyClass as:

```
var obj1 = new MyClass("test");
obj1.data.Add(CustomObject1);
obj1.data.Add(CustomObject2);
```

The next step I do is serialize and deserialize the object.

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();         
var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj1, jsonSerializerSettings);
var deserializedUserObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(serializedObject, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Now, when I try to add `CustomObject1` back to the deserialized object (which is already present), it still adds to the set.

Not sure why this is happening.
Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: How do your comparer & serialization work?

Comment: I think you need to add JsonConstructor otherwise it uses default parameterless ctor. Here is a link to a possible duplicate question for assistance -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017716/json-net-how-to-deserialize-without-using-the-default-constructor

Comment: The problem is that `HashSet<T>` is a collection, so [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Lists) doesn't serialize the comparer (or other properties) of your `HashSet<T>`, it only serializes the items.  See for instance [Set the comparer for Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert to use for HashSet/Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41875114/3744182) or [Json.NET Dictionary<string,T> with StringComparer serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20976338/3744182) for possible workarounds.

Comment: Why do you use `ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace`?

Comment: @SLaks The serialization is a default implementation of the JsonSerializationSettings and I have added the comparer to the question.

Comment: @dbc I have removed that now. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This passed when I created a default constructor and initialized the `data` parameter as below.

```
public MyClass()
{
    data = new HashSet<T>(new CustomComparer());
}
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to achieve this. 
As there will be multiple instances of the data object being created unnecessarily.
 **Is there any better way to get this done?**

Imposing a `[JsonConstructor]` property on top of the parameterized constructor didn't work too.

NOTE: I removed the `ObjectCreationHandling` property from the JsonProperty attribute.